# Maximal tamely ramified extension of $\mathbf Q_p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, local-fields, galois-groups

Is there an explicit description of the maximal tamely ramified extension of $\mathbf Q_p$?

Comment: You can find it in Chapter 16 of Hasse's *Number Theory*, not just for ${\bf Q}_p$ but also for any complete discretely valued field with finite residue field.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is. The maximal unramified extension is obtained by adding all roots of unity of order prime to $p$. The maximal tame extension is obtained by adding on top of that all $n$-th roots of $p$, for $n$ prime to $p$; so its Galois group is isomorphic to $\prod_{\ell \ne p} \mathbf{Z}_\ell$, and conjugation by $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_p^{nr} / \mathbf{Q}_p)\cong \widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$ acts on each $\mathbf{Z}_\ell$ factor via the $\ell$-adic cyclotomic character.

(EDIT: For a reference for this see Pete Clark's notes at [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/8410Chapter4.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410Chapter4.pdf), in particular Theorem 11 and Corollary 12.)

Comment: David, the Galois group of the maximal unramified extension of ${\bf Q}_p$ is $\hat{\bf Z}$, not $\hat{\bf Z}^\times$.

Comment: Oops, that was silly! I have edited the answer to correct this, thanks for spotting it.